# Why does 'this' not work in a helper class instantiated in a React functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a helper class as below, where I have to usew `self = this`. Otherwise I get `TypeError: funcA is not a function`:

```
class Helper {
  constructor() {
    self = this;
  }

  funcA = () => {
    console.log('func a');
  }

  funcB = () => {
    self.funcA();
    // this.funcA() <- Gives TypeError this.funcA is not a function. console log shows it as undefined.
  }
}

export default Helper;
```

I am using it in a functional component as follows:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import Helper from './helper';



const Component = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const helper = new Helper();
    helper.funcB();
  }, []);
};

export default Component;
```

I do not understand why I need to use `self`. Doesn't React instantiate the Helper class in the `useEffect` once (and only once), so shouldn't the `helper` variable always refer to the same instance?

Also is there a tidier way to implement a helper class? I believe I can use a custom hook, but I would like to keep the business loginc in Vanilla JS classes as I find these easier to work with and they have tidier syntax.

---

**T.J. Crowder example:**

Here it is if I don't use `self`:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

class Helper {
  funcA = () => {
    console.log('func a');
  };

  funcB = () => {
    this.funcA();
  };
}

const Component = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const helper = new Helper();
    helper.funcB();
  }, []);
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Component />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

---

**EDIT** The problem is related to using setTimeout, where the context of `this` is lost.

For completeness here is an example where I get the error:

```
class Helper {
  funcA = () => {
    console.log('func a');
  }

  doTick = () => {
    this.funcA();  // Gives TypeError this.funcA is not a function
  }

  funcB = () => {    
    setTimeout(this.doTick, 1000);
  }
}

export default Helper;
```

I will post the solution as an answer to help future readers.

Comment: What you've said doesn't work works just fine. I've added a Stack Snippet to your question using `this` for the call you've shown and fixing one obvious typo (`class` instead of `const`). Running it produces the expected result ("func a" in the console). If there's actually a problem, please edit the snippet to replicate it. Not only do you not need `self`, but what you're doing with `self` there is incorrect, as you're trying to write to the **global** [`self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self) variable, which is read-only.

Comment: Thanks for the working example. I will compare it to my implementation and update in a few hours.

Comment: I was able to track down the problem thanks to you verifying that `this` should work. Updated the question and posted the solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved using an arrow function in the `setTimeout` callback to make sure `this` correctly refers to the parent object:

```
class Helper {
  funcA = () => {
    console.log('func a');
  }

  doTick = () => {
    this.funcA();
  }

  funcB = () => {    
    setTimeout(() => { this.doTick() }, 1000);
  }
}

export default Helper;
```

Comment: FWIW, since `doTick` is an arrow function, you can simplify `funcB`: `funcB = () => { setTimeout(this.doTick, 1000); };`

Comment: Useful to know, cheers.